# GCP Global External Load balance redirect www to non www sites

Tags: networking, gcp-load-balancer

I have deployed our website as a Cloud Run service.

Added a Global external load balancer as per the doc listed in this link [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/integrate/custom-domain-load-balancer)

Everything is perfect and My website is now runnings as `https://example.com`

I am currently exploring redirecting `www.example.com` to `https://example.com` .

Tried adding a Host and path rule by editing the custom-domains http with the following yaml config for `www.example.com` .

```
defaultService: projects/xyz/global/backendServices/custom-domains-example-com-example-49a4-be
name: matcher1
routeRules:
- urlRedirect:
stripQuery: true
hostRedirect: example.com
matchRules:
- prefixMatch: /
priority: 1
```

Now I am able to redirect `www.example.com` to `https://example.com` . However if I access `www.example.com/page1,` it redirects me to `https://example.com` instead of `https://example.com/page1` .

Can you assist me on how can I acheive this.

Also, let me know if this is the best practice to be followed as well.

Regards

Srinivasan